# Google Play Testing Link Redirected to Application in Production

Tags: google-play, beta-testing

I am trying to update an application from the Google Play Console. The new version of the apk is uploaded as a beta test and I have obtained a link to download the beta test app. However, the link just redirects me to the Google Play where the current version of the app is shown.

Is there something wrong with my operations?? The testing link is obtained in the beta test page tab, from the link in "Beta testers" box. Does anyone know how I can obtain a link to the beta test app rather than the currently published version??? Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Per:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

You need to be registered as a member of a Google + or Google Group that is designated for Beta or Alpha testing by the Developer. If you are not registered, you will only be able to download the production app from Google Play, NOT the Beta or Alpha version of the app from Google Play.

Having the "link" won't be sufficient,  you need to opt-in to the beta or alpha via Google + or Google Group.

Please note that even if you properly opt-in via Google + or Google Groups as defined by the developer, you will need to wait several hours (perhaps 2-8 hours) for your status to propagate via Google Play.

So, perhaps you need to wait 2-8 hours even if your Beta/Alpha status is proper?

Hope this helps!